# TSQL see if column is part of unique index without using dynamic management function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query to see information about whether a column in a table is part of a unique index or not.
Usually i write the following to get the information I need:

```
SELECT name
    , is_part_of_unique_key
      FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Department', NULL, 1)
     WHERE is_hidden = 0
```

the "is_part_of_unique_key" from the above query does the following according to MS:

> Returns 1 if the column is part of a unique index (including unique
>   and primary constraints) and 0 if it is not. Returns NULL if it cannot
>   be determined that the column is part of a unique index. Is only
>   populated if browsing information is requested.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

however I am in a situation where I dont have SELECT-permissions on the above mentioned table, so the query above will not work.

I need the information about whether the column is part of a unique index or not by looking at i.e. the INFORMATION_SCHEMA-views

I have permissions to do the following for instance, but this doesn't give me information about unique indexes:

```
SELECT 
  COLUMN_NAME AS name
  ,DATA_TYPE AS system_type_name
  ,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
  IS_NULLABLE 

FROM   
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
            TABLE_NAME LIKE 'dbo.Department'
```

I am in doubt if sys.indexes will give me the correct results since i am interested in if the "*column is
part of a unique index (including unique and primary constraints)*"

So I am only interested in unique indexes. How would I write a query to see if the column is part of a unique index with the restriced permissions i have?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: There is information about INFORMATION_SCHEMA-views already freely available on the internet.   What research have you done, and what specific question has this led you to?

Comment: Why don't ask for the permission you require or ask db admin to create a view for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will give you a list of unique indexes and columns involved with that index. Modify the where clause accordingly:

```
SELECT sys.indexes.name, sys.columns.name
FROM       sys.tables 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes       ON sys.tables.object_id        = sys.indexes.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ON sys.indexes.object_id       = sys.index_columns.object_id
                            AND sys.indexes.index_id        = sys.index_columns.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns       ON sys.index_columns.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
                            AND sys.index_columns.column_id = sys.columns.column_id
WHERE sys.tables.name       = 'table name'
  AND sys.indexes.is_unique = 1
```

Comment: Quite complicated and does not consider a primary key, which is also unique and asked in the original question ("column is part of a unique index (including unique and primary constraints").  Answer from @kreadyf works like a charm.

Comment: @florian the joins contain all information including the reason for uniqueness (is_primary_key and is_unique). replace the column names with `*` to find what details are available.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have this table:

```
    CREATE TABLE MyIndexTestTable
    (
        MyIndexTestTableId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
        code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        otherUnique VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(100) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_MyIndexTestTable PRIMARY KEY(MyIndexTestTableId),
        CONSTRAINT UQ2_MyIndexTestTable UNIQUE (otherUnique)
    )
```

Then with the following statement you will get all columns with UNIQUE 
constraint and which are part of the primary key:

```
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS uniqueColumns FROM sys.objects c JOIN sys.objects t ON c.parent_object_id = t.object_id 
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu ON cu.TABLE_NAME = t.name AND cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.name
    WHERE c.type IN ('PK', 'UQ')
    AND t.name = 'MyIndexTestTable'
```

This answer does not cover cases in which the primary key contains multiple columns - each of them are not unique. For this case you have to alter the query in order to exclude all primary key columns, if there is more than one. Please comment if you also need this example.

Comment: Works like a charm. You can also exclude multiple PK's with a simple PARTITION BY.

Answer (score 0):

Something like sp_help has the Column `index_description`. You can pull it from that Logic

```
sp_helptext sp_help
```

Grab it from this Section in the Procedure  -- DISPLAY TABLE INDEXES & CONSTRAINTS
This may Work for you.

[Sp_help My Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gV4F.png)